# Estoy tratando de acceder a documentos json a través del ciclo for con python

Tags: python, json, datos

Estoy intentando este código:

```
import json
import urllib.request

respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen("*http://ergast.com/api/f1/seasons.json*")
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
introducir el código aquíprint(cuerpo_respuesta)
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
for s1 in json_respuesta ["MRData"]["SeasonTable"]['Seasons'][0]['season'][:]:
    print(f"Season: {s1}")
```

dándome como respuesta:
1
9
5
0
lo puse en vertical pero me lo cambió a horizontal que es como a mi me sirve

Si bien es cierto que ya estoy accediendo a los datos, mi necesidad es que yo los necesito en forma horizontal, en type int, con la finalidad de seguir ocupando la variable año, dejo una copia del código, esta arriba y del formato json, ojalá pudieran orientarme,

```
JSON
    MRData
        xmlns : "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4"
        series : "f1"
        url : "http://ergast.com/api/f1/seasons.json"
        limit : "30"
        offset : "0"
        total : "72"
        SeasonTable
            Seasons
            0
                season : "1950"
                url : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Formula_One_season"**
            1
            2
            3
            4
            5
            6
            7
            8
            9
           10
           11
           12 así hasta el veitinueve
```

Lo que yo quiero es obtener el año de

MRData.SeasonTable.Seasons> de esta ruta obtener el año alojado en season y la url alojada en url, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Con este código:

```py
for s1 in json_respuesta["MRData"]["SeasonTable"]['Seasons'][0]['season'][:]:
    print(f"Season: {s1}")
```

Estás recorriendo la cadena `"1950"` como si fuese una lista, por eso te muestra cada carácter en una línea (en *"vertical"*, como dices). Si lo que quieres es obtener el año y url de la primera *season* solo tienes que acceder a ellos con el nombre de sus claves:

```py
import json
import urllib.request

respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ergast.com/api/f1/seasons.json")
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
first_season = json_respuesta ["MRData"]["SeasonTable"]['Seasons'][0]
year = first_season['season']
url = first_season['url']
print("Season year: %s" % year)
print("Season url: %s" % url)
```

Si, en cambio, quieres acceder a cada *season* puedes recorrer la lista:

```py
import json
import urllib.request

respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ergast.com/api/f1/seasons.json")
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))

for season in json_respuesta ["MRData"]["SeasonTable"]['Seasons']:
    print("Season year: %s" % season['season'])
    print("Season url: %s" % season['url'])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose Antonio Castro, fue muy esclarecedora tu ayuda, solo te comento, intuiste bien que lo que yo necesito es el año y la url en un solo renglón, y lo resolví no especificando key y de este modo me devolvió todos los value

Comment: for season in json_respuesta ["MRData"]["SeasonTable"]['Seasons']:
    print("Season year: %s" % season

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya llevaba atorado aqui mudos semanas,

Comment: Otra pregunta, empiezo con postgresql, existe alguna manera de extraer las bases de datos de en este caso ergast, digamos importar de ergast a mi base de datos,  y en tu experiencia, mi pagina correra más eficientemente si tomo los datos directamente desde mi servidor (DB alojada en Postgres), o resulta lo mismo si los tomo desde ergast?

Comment: o ya teniéndolo en python lo puedo subir a Postgres, sabras como puedo hacerle, gracias

Comment: Hola @alemdez. Ergast comparte las bases de datos completas: [http://ergast.com/mrd/db/](http://ergast.com/mrd/db/). Si puedes usar MySQL en vez de Postgres podrás actualizar los datos nuevos más fácilmente, ya que la comparten en ese formato. Y, si son datos críticos en tu proyecto yo utilizaría mi propia base de datos antes de depender de un servicio externo.